# How to maximize total points?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math

Given an array A[1:N]. Every element of the array is non-negative.
Operation allowed: Pick two elements of the array(value of both elements must be atleast 1) and reduce both element by 1. This way we will earn 1 point. What is the maximum points that can be earned?

Example:

```
A[1:3] = 1 1 2
After step 1: 0 1 1
After step 2: 0 0 0
Maximum points = 2
```

Brute force approach:

```
total_points <- 0
while value of atleast two elements of A is greater than 0:
      subtract 1 from both
      total_points <- total_points + 1
return total_points
```

How to improve the approach? Please help.

Comment: Think about overall sum and about maximum element value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can sum up all the values. Lets call this MAX.
Then you check if there is a single element that holds more than MAX/2, lets call this Element BIG.
If this Condition is not met then the answer should simply be MAX/2.
If this Condition however is met then we have to subtract 1 from BIG and from MAX until BIG is smaller or equal to MAX/2.

Comment: We will also have to assume MAX is even if it is not then we simply subtract 1 before beginning the procedure.

Comment: If you take the approach to allways pick the two highest values you will result in the optimal sum. and you subtract 2 from MAX each time you add 1 to total points. So the only Problem that can occur is if the highest value can not be completly reduced, or MAX is odd. Sorry I dont know how to better explain this.

Comment: "If this Condition however is met then we have to subtract 1 from BIG and from MAX until BIG is smaller or equal to MAX/2" can be simplified as sum of all the elements except the biggest one. Am I right.

Comment: Yes your right we can simplify it to the sum of all elements except the biggest one, but of course only if the biggest one is too big.

Comment: If there is an element greater than MAX/2 in the array then the answer will be sum of rest of the elements(logic is clear to me).

Comment: But if there is no value greater than MAX/2 then the answer will be MAX/2. How? Please explain this part.